# Use a single record of a file with multiple columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Let's say I have the following data stored in the file 'file' (exciting!):

```
a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3
b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3
...
```

and also a given function f.
I want to draw several plots, one after the other, each consisting of a single point in (x,y) coordinates : a_2,f(a_2), then b_2,f(b_2), etc.

I want to use a gnuplot-only solution (and I think there must be one, although I can't find it !).

I am looking for something like :

```
plot 'file' every ::0::0: using ($2):(f($2))
pause -1
plot 'file' every ::1::1: using ($2):(f($2))
...
```

I seem to be doing something too complicated... Thanks for any help !

Comment: The column numbers start at `1`, `0` is the row number. So with `plot 'file' every ::0::0 using 3:(f($3))` it should work fine.

Comment: Yes you're right Christoph. But it's a typo I made !  Your suggestion doesn't work either.

Comment: @Christoph I really want to draw a single point.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. And I don't see the problem or error you're having with it. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works fine for me. Take a data file `file`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9
```

And then use:

```
f(x) = x**2
plot 'file' every ::0::0 using 3:(f($3))
```

That plots me a single point at `(2, 4)`. For an automatic iteration use e.g.

```
stats 'file' using 0 nooutput
do for [i=0:int(STATS_records-1)] {
    plot 'file' every ::i::i using 3:(f($3))
    pause -1
}
```

Comment: Dear Christoph, it works now ! I removed the ':' at the end, i.e. what works is 'every ::0::0' as you stated and NOT 'every ::0::0:' as I had previously tried.  Do you know why ?

Comment: I haven't noticed that semicolon at the end. I guess its a limitation of the parsing of the `every` expression which doesn't allow an ending semicolon. However, this is either a bug in the parsing, or the documenation must be adapted, which currently says: `Any of the numbers can be omitted; the increments default to unity...` (see `help every`). But I do also get an error with `every ::0::0:`, `undefined variable using`, didn't you get one, too?

Comment: With `every ::0::0:1` it is OK for me. Is that what you meant ?    With `every ::0::0:` I get the error `undefined variable using`.    I use Gnuplot on a remote machine with version 4.4 patchlevel 2.    I agree with your remark on the documentation, as it was my source for my line of code !!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll report that to the gnuplot developers.

Comment: Thanks Christoph.    As a matter of fact, my complete command is `plot 'file' every ::0::0 using 3:(f($3)),f(x)`    and I got the following message    `empty x range [2:2], adjusting to [1.98:2.02]`     so that I don't get any relevant information for the whole function f...    Do you know why Gnuplot does that ?

Comment: Because if you have autoscaling and plot a data file and a function together, the range is determined by the data. Since you plot a single point, the range would be empty, and gets extended a bit. Use e.g. `set xrange [0:10]` to set a fixed range.

Comment: OK, that was my intuition. I know I can use `set xrange` but I would like to avoid it if at all possible.    Isn't there an option so that the range is determined by the function ?

Comment: No, because functions can have an infinite definition domain. There is no way for gnuplot to "know" which range you want for your function. Starting with version 4.6 you can use the `stats` function to determine the range of the third column and use that later for plotting: `stats 'file' using 3; set xrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]; plot ...`. With 4.4 you need a workaround: First plot the total data range. Then you have access to the variables `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX`: `plot 'file' u 3:(f($3)); set xrange [GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX]; plot 'file' u 3:(f($3)) every ::0::0`

Comment: OK. I thought there would be a way for gnuplot to "know" because it does autoscaling when plotting only a function.    Gnuplot version 4.6 looks good, I have emailed my system administrator to request an upgrade ! Thanks again Christoph.

Comment: For functions this is not really an autoscaling, but rather a default xrange of `[-10:10]`, which is used independent of the function definition or their behavior.

Comment: You're right. Would you be so kind as to post a link to the report (bug report ?) you made ?

Comment: I've just seen, that in 4.6.5 this was added to the documentation. In the `help every` part it says now: `"Any of the numbers can be omitted; [...]. ':' at the end of the 'every' option is not permitted."`.

Comment: Ha ha ! Tricky pitfall !